# Compare all iterations of samples pairs (from unpaired data) across groups

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I would like compare two different groups by averaging the comparison of all possible pairs of data between them.

Reproducible example

```
play <- data.frame(id = c(1:7), class=rep.int(100,7),group=c(rep.int(1,3),rep.int(2,4)), value=c(2,3,2,8,7,6,7))

  id class group value
  1   100     1     2
  2   100     1     3
  3   100     1     2
  4   100     2     8
  5   100     2     7
  6   100     2     6
  7   100     2     7
```

So I have 7 samples, all from the same class, coming from two different groups. What I would like is to calculate the ratio of group 2 / group 1 values overall by individually pairing up each possible combination of values from a group 2 and a group 1 sample, then averaging them.

So the final output value is the average of 8/2, 7/2, 6/2, 7/2, 8/3, 7/3, 6/3, 7/3, 8/2, 7/2, 6/2, 7/2 = 3.111

In my full data set I have many more classes as well, and I only want to make the comparisons within each class. The number of samples in each class/group will vary slightly.

I'm struggling with how to approach this, and afraid I'm going to end up in a sea of loops.

Comment: `v1 <- play$value[play$group==1];
v2 <- play$value[play$group==2];
mean(outer(v2, v1, '/'))` or `mean(sapply(v2, '/', v1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution.

*Note that I'm using a dataset similar to one you posted, but with 2 classes, in order to have something even closer to your real dataset.*

```
# example dataset
play2 <- data.frame(id = c(1:14), 
                    class=c(rep.int(100,7), rep.int(200,7)),
                    group=c(rep.int(1,3),rep.int(2,4)), 
                    value=c(2,3,2,8,7,6,7,2,3,2,8,7,6,10))

library(tidyverse)

# create a function to calculate average of ratios
GetAvgRatios = function(d) {

  expand.grid(d$value[d$group == 2],
              d$value[d$group == 1]) %>%
    mutate(v = Var1/Var2) %>%
    pull(v) %>%
    mean() }

# aplly function to the sub-dataset based on each class
play2 %>%
  nest(-class) %>%
  mutate(v = map(data, GetAvgRatios)) %>%
  select(class, v)

#   class        v
# 1   100 3.111111
# 2   200 3.444444
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Learned a lot about tidyverse notation working through this - still not sure I inherently understand the nest function but it certainly got the job done. I did have to use unlist to be able to export the final output as a .csv since it was giving me a list for column 'v'.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the column `value` into two vectors, then call `expand.grid` to get all pairs of elements between the vectors, then call `/` on each of those pairs with `Reduce`, then take the `mean`.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(play2)

play2[, value %>% 
          split(-group) %>% 
          do.call(what = expand.grid) %>% 
          Reduce(f = `/`) %>% 
          mean
      , by = class]

#    class       V1
# 1:   100 3.111111
# 2:   200 3.444444
```

Data used (stolen from AntoniosK answer)

```
# example dataset
play2 <- data.frame(id = c(1:14), 
                    class=c(rep.int(100,7), rep.int(200,7)),
                    group=c(rep.int(1,3),rep.int(2,4)), 
                    value=c(2,3,2,8,7,6,7,2,3,2,8,7,6,10))
```